# How can I redirect URLs using regexp?

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

When using youtube I find the pages:

https://www.youtube.com/user/USERNAME/videos and
https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNELNAME/videos

more useful than

https://www.youtube.com/user/USERNAME
https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNELNAME

Often the newest videos uploaded by my favorite youtubes are not visible on the default page of their channel.

How can I redirect the former link to the respective latter links? I've found a chrome extension that uses regexp. But it isn't working as expected... or perhaps I'm just bad at regexps.

But even if it did work I need to hit return in the URL bar to trigger it. I want this to work from youtube's menu links.

Also, is there any way to simply auto-generate a youtube playlist of videos uploaded recently by the people I'm subscribed to? It seems like a no-brainer feature but I can't find a fast way to do it without going to each channel page and checking to see if they have new content.

Thanks!

Comment: Re your last point (off-topic here) - see "video" and "list" in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#before-you-start. Also if you subscribe to channels and open a browser full screen at the YT homepage you'll see a list of channels with a count of recent unseen videos.

Comment: That information on the YT homepage is often highly inaccurate. So much so that I don't even consider it useful. Thanks for the link, though.